# Don't include weekends for the fanatic badge consecutive days calculation

Tags: feature-request, badges, consecutive-days, activity-badges

So I visit the site during the work week... I mean, it's a great stress relief to read other peoples coding problems and try to help them rather to work on your own coding bugs.

But during the weekend, I mostly spend it drinking, instead of on stack overflow (sorry guys).

I was wondering, if the consecutive days of the fanatic badge should include weekends... I consider myself a fanatic, but even a fanatic gets to take the weekend off, right?

I guess, I am suggesting that we take off the weekend requirement to be consecutive. Obviously, I won't include weekends in the count either. This would actually make it longer to achieve the fanatic badge, because weekends don't count.

For every 5 days you have a weekend.

```
100 / 5
        = 20 weekday periods

20 * 2 (weekends)
                      = 40 extra days
```

So they would have to wait 40 days longer, but not visit the site on weekends.

---

Furthermore, we don't have to remove the current system... we can have the both in place like this:

**To receive the fanatic badge you could do either of these requirements:**

- Visit the site for 100 days consecutively  (currently what it is)

OR

- Visit the site for 100 consecutive weekdays (holiday's and weekends don't count) (approximately 140 days wait in length)

---

To show an example using freehand circles

[image]

Comment: actually, this does not sound like a bad idea

Comment: What about someone who has an odd work week and their "weekend" is Monday and Tuesday? My first job was like that...

Comment: It doesn't sound very fanatical to take the weekends off. You can't just click once to load the site? I am sure there is a minute of clarity somewhere in that drunken haze :P

Comment: @animuson I guess SO would have to decide what they want to do for people like that... but the majority of the people have Saturday and Sunday off. Also, notice how I never defined weekend...

Comment: Having weekends off is not fanatical, I mean I was on SO on my wedding day... You must visit everyday to be a fanatic.

Comment: You have to visit it once every 24 hours. That’s not really a lot to ask…

Comment: @bluefeet ah, that's the requirement for the 'divorce' badge. I think that's a gold one.

Comment: @JonW and you can get the 'divorce' badge multiple times!

Comment: @JonW - You lose half your rep when you get the divorce badge though :(

Comment: Fanatics don't take weekends off.  There's always the Enthusiast badge though. You can go 30 days and get a shiny silver badge.

Comment: In Israel friday is already weekend but Sunday is a regular working day. The same with the Saturday adventists. Moslims have something similar as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> But during the weekend, I mostly spend it drinking, instead of on stack overflow

Sorry, but *true* fanatics don't take breaks. You should consider browsing Stack Overflow while drunk, *trust me*, it's a lot more fun.

Furthermore, this seems like an overcomplicated solution for extremely little - if any - benefit. It's just a silly badge, after all.

Comment: I've done this - I think I might have answered questions while drunk, but don't remember

Comment: Touché, I haven't thought of that possibility! I must try this!

Comment: @Arian Bottoms up!

Comment: @Arian if you want to feel like Jon Skeet, browse Stack Overflow *while you're asleep*! :D

Comment: @Yannis Now I wish I got a badge for being drunk on SO... :/

Comment: I've got a new game to play on New Years' Eve now.  This is going to be **awesome.**  All joking aside, I agree with your sentiment.

Comment: +1 for the "*true* fanatics" part. I'd give another +1 for the "silly badge" part if I could!

Comment: Being anywhere near a computer whilst drunk is extremely dangerous.  Play safe and go and operate some heavy machinery instead or try some chainsaw juggling.

Comment: I upvoted for all of the people who wished they could upvote again.

Comment: In fact, I think browsing SO while drunk is quite popular. I think a lot of people are reluctant to post while they're drunk because they're afraid they'll say something stupid and get heavily downvoted, so they go and review suggested edits instead. That's the only way I can explain how so many ridiculous edit suggestions end up getting approved.